# How to use a table in Cucumber with Ruby to verify data on web form

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I am using Cucumber with Ruby and Watir webdriver.

What I am trying to do is verify that data that is pre-populated on a web form matches the data in a table in the features file in Cucumber. I need help in writing the Ruby code in the step definitions file. Here is what I have so far:

```
Cucumber feature: 
Then I will be able to view my information pre-populated from IAM as follows:

|First Name/Given Name  |Chimwemwe       |
|Last Name/Surname      |Rossi           |
|Country                |USA             |
|Address                |fdafda          |
|City                   |fdafd           |
|State                  |Louisana        |
|Postal Code            |99999           |

Then (/^I will be able to view my information pre-populated from IAM.$/) do   |table|
    information = table.rows_hash
    information.each do |entry|
    contact_info = entry [0]
    if @browser.text_field(:name=>'firstName').verify_contains(contact_info[0])==true
        puts "Passed"
    else
        puts "Failed"
    end
end
```

I am only doing the first row for now until I get it to work. I would like it to eventually iterate through the table.

when I try to run the script all I get is this error: #table is a Cucumber::Core::Ast::DataTable.

I am fairly new to Ruby/Cucumber and this is the most complicated script I have written so far. Any help on how to do this would be really helpful. I know I need an array, but i have been looking at so much of this online, I feel like my brain is going to explode. Thanks.

Comment: Where does `verify_contains` come from? I don't think that is Watir, so are you using another gem to supplement Watir?

Comment: You might want to review https://github.com/styleguide/ruby/syntax.. it won't help you with actual code (such as how to access elements of a hash) but it will help you present the code in a way that at least looks like proper ruby code ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have an easy way to map the Cucumber table to the Watir fields, iteration might not be useful. The simplest approach is to directly check that each field under test matches the table.

I am not sure which assertion library you are using, but as an example, the following uses the RSpec Expectations:

```
Then (/^I will be able to view my information pre-populated from IAM.$/) do |table|
  information = table.rows_hash

  expect(@browser.text_field(:name=>'firstName').value).to eq(information['First Name/Given Name'])
  expect(@browser.text_field(:name=>'lastName').value).to eq(information['Last Name/Surname'])
  # etc. for each field
end
```

Note that the test will fail at the first incorrect field. If you want to assert all of the fields at once, you can retrieve them into a `Hash` and compare it to the table:

```
Then (/^I will be able to view my information pre-populated from IAM.$/) do |table|
  form_fields = {
    'First Name/Given Name' => @browser.text_field(:name=>'firstName').value,
    'Last Name/Surname' => @browser.text_field(:name=>'lastName').value
  }
  expect(form_fields).to eq(table.rows_hash)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. The second option worked perfectly. I figured that was how I was going to have to do it, but this option keeps the script running even if one of the validations fail.